# NullPointerException when setting OnClickListener in method

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am creating address book, but when I am adding new number and getting button from XML I am getting `NullPointerException`.
Here is the code that causes the error

```
package oo.seniorlauncher.com.o_seniorlauncher;

import oo.seniorlauncher.com.o_seniorlauncher.util.SystemUiHider;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;



public class newNumber extends Activity {

boolean ready = false;
EditText nameField;
EditText numberField;
Context context;

String name;
String number;
String place= "";
public boolean ready(){

    return ready;

}

public void run(String plac,Context context){
    this.context = context;
   place = plac;
    MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
    ((Activity) context).setContentView(R.layout.adnumber);
   set();
}public void sey(){
// this causes the error Button button= (Button)findViewById(R.id.readyButton); 
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NameField);
            numberField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Number);
            name = nameField.getText().toString();
            number =numberField.getText().toString();
            MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
            frame.adName(name,place);
            frame.adNumber(number, place);
            ((Activity) context).setContentView(R.layout.adnumber);
        }
    });
}
```

and here is the error

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2072)
        at oo.seniorlauncher.com.o_seniorlauncher.newNumber.set(newNumber.java:60)
        at oo.seniorlauncher.com.o_seniorlauncher.newNumber.run(newNumber.java:58)
        at oo.seniorlauncher.com.o_seniorlauncher.MainFrame$3.onClick(MainFrame.java:116)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

and here is my XMl-file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="oo.seniorlauncher.com.o_seniorlauncher.newNumber">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Syötä"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:textSize="50dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="numero"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:width="250dp"
    android:textSize="50dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="ja nimi"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textSize="50dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/NameField"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Nimi" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/Number"
    android:layout_below="@+id/NameField"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:text="Numero"
    android:phoneNumber="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Valmis"
    android:id="@+id/readyButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Number"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textSize="75dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried almost everything and I don't know what causes the error.

Comment: Show your layout XML file.

Comment: where are you calling these **run()** and **sey()** functions.

Comment: `newNumber` should not be an `Activity`. Never instantiate activities with `new`.

Comment: Show your onCreate() Method.

Comment: before you can use findViewById you must set the content view of course, else you get nullpointerexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont listen to the others that are suggesting moving the setContentView() to onCreate()...It's truly the best but you can set it where ever you want...until you do that you just have a black screen. Some just dont know how Android works and just copied code from tutorials. The View hierarchies you want to build , inflate and fill into an activity can be done whenever you want so everything is gonna be all right ;)

That being said show us the xml files

edit: before you do any findviewbyid you must set the content vew of course so that you can reference the single objects inside your memory else you get your nullpointer exception :)

Answer (score 1):

You must set content view in `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.adnumber);
}
```

Comment: I bet you can set the contentview everywhere you want ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your activity should have an `onCreate()` method, where you initialize your views.

Like this:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.adnumber);
    //initialize your views here
    nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NameField);
    numberField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Number);


}
```

Comment: Im sure he didnt show the whole code but nevertheless he can set the content whenever he wishes....

Answer (score 0):

You must set the content view to the activity by `setContentView("your_layout_ID")` and code for get all widget from XML file should be put on onCreate function.